# WPF app crash on Windows 10 when using international keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, culture

Testing a WPF .Net application on Windows 10 that has English international keyboard setup makes the application crash with the error `Culture ID 8192 (0x2000) is not a supported culture.`

The crash happens when typing in text boxes.

The bug could not be reproduced on Windows 7, and is solved on Windows 10 when setting another keyboard.

The target framework is .Net 3.5.

The stacktrace (in french) does not help me much, it goes directly inside Microsoft's code :

```
System.ArgumentException: L'ID de culture 8192 (0x2000) n'est pas une culture prise en charge.
Nom du paramètre : culture
   à System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(Int32 cultureId, Boolean useUserOverride)
   à System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
   à System.Windows.Input.InputLanguageSource.get_CurrentInputLanguage()
   à System.Windows.Input.InputLanguageManager.get_CurrentInputLanguage()
   à System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.EnsureCaret(Boolean isBlinkEnabled, CaretScrollMethod scrollMethod)
   à System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.System.Windows.Documents.ITextSelection.UpdateCaretAndHighlight()
   à System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor.OnGotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   à System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   à System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   à System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   à System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject focus, Int32 timestamp)
   à System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew)
   à System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
   à System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
   à System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.MoveFocusToUiScope(TextEditor This)
   à System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.OnMouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   à System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   à System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   à System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   à System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   à System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   à System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   à System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   à System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   à System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   à MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   à System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   à MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   à MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   à System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   à System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   à MyApp.App.Main()
```

Looking for help, please...

---

EDIT : Targeting .Net 4.0 solves the issue. But the sad thing is that we must target 3.5 to ensure compatibility with old OS for this app.

This fact makes the question quite odd, but I would like to leave it open in case someone can bring some help.

---

SOLUTION : It is more a turnaround than a solution : we added to 
`OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` some code to warn the user if the culture settings raise an exception and shutdown the app :

```
try
{
    CultureInfo cul = new CultureInfo(System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.LCID, true);
}
catch
{
    //warn the user...

    Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to get the error in English and google it?

Comment: Yes, but it did not helped me much...

Comment: Can you post it here for the English speaking users? (not a translation, exact message)

Comment: according to my searches it should be the second line of my post

Comment: finally googling made me find this one : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9eb4942d-9bbb-4deb-80b3-b7d98cc541f5/many-string-methods-throw-argumentexception-on-windows10-for-some-cultures-like-englisheurope?forum=netfxbcl"
"This looks like a bug in win10 of .Net Framework 3.5"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem inside a library called by my program, and no amount of fiddling with the Windows culture seemed to fix it.

In the end, after digging through the stack trace and seeing exactly what went wrong, I came up with the workaround of looping over all installed input languages, skipping the ones that had the "corrupted" Culture, and setting `System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage` to the most applicable one that remained.

Keyboard layout can be checked specifically, so taking the first one with an identical layout name should do the job without messing anything up.

The code requires a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`.

```
InputLanguage origIpl = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
Boolean fixIpl = false;
try
{
    // This causes the exception.
    CultureInfo ci = origIpl.Culture;
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    // detected the problem.
    fixIpl = true;
}
if (fixIpl)
{
    InputLanguage validIpl = null;
    InputLanguage preferredIpl = null;
    foreach (InputLanguage ipl in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
    {
        try
        {
            // This causes the exception.
            CultureInfo ci = ipl.Culture;
            // Store the first one that survives the above call
            if (validIpl == null)
                validIpl = ipl;
            // See if there is one with identical layout. If not, keep looking.
            if (origIpl.LayoutName != ipl.LayoutName)
                continue;
            // Found 1:1 match: store and abort loop.
            preferredIpl = ipl;
            break;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            /* skip languages that raise the exception here. */
        }
    }
    if (validIpl != null)
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = preferredIpl ?? validIpl;
    // else case here could give some kind of warning?
    // Not sure if it's possible to NOT have any standard input languages.
}
```

Comment: Yes it is another solution. But personally for such issues, I prefer to warn the user about the issue and let him find his solution by himself. This avoid digging in too many considerations, and lets the user keep a hand on what is going on...

Comment: well, if, like in my case, it's one specific call that causes the crash, you can always just reset it immediately after that operation is complete, so it has no real influence on whatever the user is doing. I used a `try-finally` block for that, where the `finally` part checked the `fixIpl` Boolean mentioned in the code above.